# How add and remove fragment with same button

Tags: android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am adding a fragment with `Button` click. I don't want to give a separate button to remove this fragment. So how can i remove this fragment with same button. 
I tried this

```
 case R.id.BN_Tab:

                Fragment fragment = new Fragment_Tab();
                Fragment fragment1 = mManager.findFragmentByTag("TAB FRAGMENT");

                if (!fragment.isAdded()) {
                    mManager.beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.Tabs_Container, fragment, "TAB FRAGMENT")
                            .commit();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Tab Fragment is Added");

                } else if (fragment1 != null && fragment1.isResumed()) {

                    mManager.beginTransaction()
                            .remove(fragment)
                            .commit();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Tab Fragment is Removed()" );

                }
```

This method continue adding same fragment and never trigger the `else if()` block and when i am trying to find Fragment with `Fragment fragment =  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Tabs_Container);` it give NPE.

Comment: What does NPE says. That your answer.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Tabs_Container); return null object.

Comment: Condition is not working properly as I seen it add and remove on single click of button.Instead you should handle logic in onBackPressed method of activity. replace first fragment with second on it's click

Comment: Yes my first condition not working properly. It keep adding the instance of same fragment. how can i check that fragment is already added in layout.

Comment: I thinks you should use this condition to get count you need                            
entry < fm.getBackStackEntryCount() that will return number of fragment in back-stack

Answer (score 0):

Now this simple code works for me

```
case R.id.BN_Tab:
                Fragment fragment = mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.Tabs_Container);
                if (fragment==null) {
                    mManager.beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.Tabs_Container, new Fragment_Tab(), "TAB FRAGMENT")
                            .commit();

                } else  {
                    mManager.beginTransaction()
                            .remove(fragment)
                            .commit();
                }
```

Comment: I find when Fragment is not added into container it always returning null. So this is what i want.